# Google Ads and Tag Assistant showing my remarketing event snippet as invalid

Tags: shopify, google-ads-api, google-remarketing-audience

I just added a Remarketing event snippet for a dynamic remarketing campaign to product pages in my store. here is an example of the code rendered on the page:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXX'); </script>

<script>
 gtag('event', 'page_view', {
 'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXX',
 'google_business_vertical' : 'retail',
 'id' : 'YYYYYYYYYY',                        // Google Merchant Center ID
 'ecomm_pagetype': 'product',
 'ecomm_prodid': 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz',
 'ecomm_totalvalue': '255.00'
 });
</script>
```

This looks correct to me, but Google Tag Assistant extension says there's an error:
[image]

When I click 'Requests' and go to the 2nd one, it shows the following meta data:
[image]

which again, looks correct to me.

Also, when I go Google Ads --> Audience Manager --> Audience Sources --> Google Ads Tag, it tells me there's an issue:
Issue: ecomm_prodid never received

This is very confusing since ​ecomm_prodid is present and has a vale in the meta data above. I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong. If anyone can help troubleshooting or sees something wrong to begin with, I'd be most appreciative.

The scripts are being added to the  tag of a Shopify theme... in case that matters.

Thanks!!

Comment: In my experience, the Tag Assistant isn't always very reliable. You could try using your browser's developer tools and looking for requests to `googleads.g.doubleclick.net`. If they show up, you should be able to inspect the query string and check whether `ecomm_prodid` is being sent.

Comment: @dorian - thanks! Super frustrating for that tool not to work reliably - shame on Google. The 3 parameters are present in the query string for that file, so I guess that means the page is communicating with Google Ads properly, correct? Now my other problem is that in Google Ads for the Google Ads Tag Audience Source I'm getting 2 errors: `92% of id values received in the past day didn't match your feed` and `96% of audience source activity missing id in the last day`. Any ideas on either of those?

Comment: Regarding the first warning, are you sure that the product IDs you send are exactly the same ones that you have in your product feed? As for the other one—do you use dynamic remarketing snippets on other pages that might not include the required information?

Comment: I'll have to check the product IDs with the client - there's a chance they're not matching the format from the feed. And just to confirm, in the object I'm sending, `ecom_prodid` should be the product ID from the feed and `id` should be the Google Merchant Center ID, correct?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes.